# Turn on adb over wi-fi on ginerbread via terminal

Tags: android, adb, root, smart-tv

I have an Android Smart TV with locked bootloader, but enabled root access. It doesn't allow to remount `/system` as read/write-able, so I can not install something like Superuser, but there is a `sudo` app (no `su` binary, however).

In short, to access the device I need to turn on `adb` over Wifi (it does not have any USB ports) to debug my app.

Is it possible to do this over terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the process mentioned [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1685736) since you have some sort of `root` access. However I'm not familiar with Android TV's so that may or may not work.

Also, you mentioned root access but no `su` binary and instead you have `sudo`? If you have **any** sort of escalated privileges you should be able to remount `/system` as read/write and install Superuser.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which device you are talking about. But the following sequence works in Sony Google TV

Both google tv and desktop should be in same network.

1. select Applications > Development, enable Remote debugging
2. In the debugger IP address, enter your pc's ip address(from where you want to debug)
   Note down the google tv's ip address

From your pc,

adb connect 192.168.0.101:5555 (replace 192.168.0.101 with your google tv's ip address)

Now you can all regular adb commands like adb install etc

Comment: This menu is removed from the settings.